# Vue.js don't bind element replaced in an array. It works with splice.... why?

Tags: rest, data-binding, vuejs2

I want to update the record base on the server response and refresh the data table without fetching the whole list. 
I found a solution but don't understand why **this.items[this.editedIndex] = payload.data** is !OK and ** this.items.splice(this.editedIndex, 1, payload.data)** is OK.

```
save() {
      fetch(this.api + "/" + this.editedItem.id, {
          method: "PUT",
          body: JSON.stringify(this.editedItem),
          headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json"
          }
        })
         .then(payload => payload.json())
         .then(payload => {
            this.items.splice(this.editedIndex, 1, payload.data) // THIS WORKS!!
            //this.items[this.editedIndex] = payload.data // THIS DOESN'T... WHY?
          })
          .catch()
      }
```

Comment: This is a standard reactivity caveat for working with arrays: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays. The reason is that there's no way for Vue to detect the change (without using proxies, which weren't available when Vue 2 was written).

Comment: Also, `splice()` mutates the array in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue can't detect directly updating an index in case of an array so use `Vue.set` method or it's alias `$set` method.

```
this.$set(this.items, this.editedIndex, payload.data)
```

Refer : [Change Detection Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays)

Comment: Reactivity works fine with nested properties. The problem here is updating an array directly by index.

Comment: @skirtle : yes you are right, thanks for correcting :)